# Why am I getting "Received fatal alert: protocol_version" or "peer not authenticated" from Maven Central?

Tags: maven, maven-central

I'm getting the below errors when connecting to Maven Central / https://repo1.maven.org after June 18th 2018.

```
Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

or

```
Received fatal alert: peer not authenticated
```

Comment: Impressive test you did there for the future.

Comment: Switching to Java 11 resolve the error.

Answer (score 242):

**Solution 1: configure Java 7**

It is need to enable TLS 1.2 protocol with Java property in the command line

```
mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 install
```

`install` is just an example of a goal

The same error for `ant` can be solved by this way

```
java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -cp %ANT_HOME%/lib/ant-launcher.jar org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

**Solution 2: use Java 7 with Oracle Advanced Support**

Also problem can be solved by updating the Java 7 version. But the last available version (`7u80`) doesn't fix the problem. It is need to use an update provided with Oracle Advanced Support (formerly known as Java for Business).

**Solution 3: use Java 8 or above instead**

Configure `$JAVA_HOME` to point to Java 8.

**Sonatype FAQ about the issue**

[Discontinued support for TLSv1.1 and below](https://central.sonatype.org/faq/tls-info/)

Comment: Can you tell me please what's the equivalent in SBT
I tried `sbt -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 instal`but it does not work

Comment: @G.Saleh You need the way to pass this parameter to java `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`. So you need to find how to pass java parameters in SBT.

Answer (score 69):

In June 2018, in an effort to raise security and comply with modern standards, the insecure TLS 1.0 & 1.1 protocols will no longer be supported for SSL connections to Central. This should only affect users of Java 6 (and Java 7) that are also using https to access central, which by our metrics is less than .2% of users.

For more details and workarounds, see the blog and faq here: https://blog.sonatype.com/enhancing-ssl-security-and-http/2-support-for-central

Comment: The link in the blog.sonatype.com article is throwing 404. It is because they updated the link to https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2018/May/04/discontinued-support-for-tlsv11-and-below/.

Answer (score 62):

The following command helped me (executing on bash before running mvn)

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Comment: On Windows
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Comment: after setting this all http download is working for me. however https has issue as below
Failed to collect dependencies at org.netpreserve.commons:webarchive-commons:jar:1.1.2 -> org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:0.20.2-cdh3u4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:0.20.2-cdh3u4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:pom:0.20.2-cdh3u4 from/to cloudera (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure 
any help

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! (Tried on CentOs)

Comment: Is this secure?

Comment: Thank You! This got it going for me!

Comment: I've used the export with the 1.2 version only and it worked for me. It is also the secure way as documented: `export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`

Answer (score 25):

As said @v.ladynev, it works with JDK 1.7

With Eclipse, to be able to perform a "Run As" `maven install` with the TLS command-line parameter, just configure the JDK you're using.

Open the dialog through ***Window*** > ***Preferences*** > ***Java*** > ***Installed JREs***.

Then highlight the one you're using (should be a **JDK**, not a **JRE**), click on ***Edit***. In the field "Default VM arguments", fill the value `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`. As shown below:

[image]

Clean the project (maybe optional), then re-run a `maven install`.

Comment: I am getting this 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.netpreserve.commons:webarchive-commons:jar:1.1.2 -> org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:0.20.2-cdh3u4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:0.20.2-cdh3u4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:pom:0.20.2-cdh3u4 from/to cloudera (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure 
looks https download has issue . please help I am using java1.7_80 and maven 3.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188983/discussion-between-amessihel-and-liz-lamperouge).

Answer (score 9):

I'm sorry, I don't know why you get the error message. However, I'm using Java 7 and Windows 10 and the solution for me was to temporarily use Java 8 by changing the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Then I could run `mvn install` and fetch from Maven Central Repository.

Comment: This worked wonders for me.  As a user of MyEclipse, all I had to do was to change the JRE for the maven run configuration to 1.8 and then back again to 1.7 after maven had downloaded what it needed.

Answer (score 4):

Update maven version to 3.6.3 and run

```
mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 install
```

it worked on centos 6.9

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you're using the IBM JDK you may also have to set

`com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/matchsslcontext_tls.html#matchsslcontext_tls

Answer (score 3):

Add "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" to "Default VM arguments" under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs in Eclipse, validate and run your project, it should and will work.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail on why this is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Using jdk7-u221, I was need to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)

[Java Cryptography Extension JCE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)

Answer (score 0):

For setting java properties on Windows app server:

- configure tomcat > run as admin
- then add Java opts:
- restart service.

Comment: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Comment: & -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2