# Maven exception "Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved"

Tags: maven

[image: Centos Maven problem]

i have a problem that i can't execute this order "mvn clean package -DskipTes" in my vitural machine (centos)

Comment: Side comment: This version is ~6 years old. You should probably try using a newer one.

Comment: it's my first big data demo,so i just use it in recently,and when i finished this demo,i will using a newer one.

Comment: The message `protocol version` shows that you are going with Java 6 or Java 7...See https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2018/May/04/discontinued-support-for-tlsv11-and-below/

Comment: so appreciate,buddy!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've missed the message that Maven Central now only supports TLSv1.2, see [Why am I getting "Received fatal alert: protocol_version" or "peer not authenticated" from Maven Central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic)