# Why Error resolving version for plugin maven only jdk7? on jdk8 no error

Tags: java, maven, gitlab-ci

I try simple maven project on gitlab.com

Link: https://gitlab.com/anton_patsev/maven-simple

Added standart `.gitlab-ci.yml` for maven

Project compile for jdk7 and jdk8.

jdk7 have [Error resolving version for plugin](https://gitlab.com/anton_patsev/maven-simple/-/jobs/78596128)

jdk8 compile [passed](https://gitlab.com/anton_patsev/maven-simple/-/jobs/78596129)

Setting is same.
Why Error resolving version for plugin maven only jdk7?
How fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've missed the message that Maven Central now only supports TLSv1.2, see [Why am I getting "Received fatal alert: protocol_version" or "peer not authenticated" from Maven Central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic)
Based on the logging, you're missing an explicit version for 2 plugins. That's a reason for Maven to go to Central to look for the most recent version.
The mentioned SO-answer is contains several solutions, but it is also wise to lock the versions for these plugins to prevent lookups at Central.