# Why am I getting javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version for ant?

Tags: java, maven, ssl, ant, ivy

I am getting this error after June 2018:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.openConnection(Get.java:731)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.get(Get.java:652)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.run(Get.java:642)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `ant` downloads some artifacts from the Maven Central, using `ivy` plugin for example.
Java 7 uses the old TLS protocol version by default.
In June 2018 the TLS 1.0 & 1.1 protocols will no longer be supported for SSL connections to Maven Central.

[Why am I getting "Received fatal alert: protocol_version" or "peer not authenticated" from Maven Central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic)

It can be solved at least for Java 7 by specifying TLS version as a *java system property*.

All examples run a default ant task.

**For Windows**

```
java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -cp %ANT_HOME%/lib/ant-launcher.jar org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

**For Linux**

```
java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -cp ${ANT_HOME}/lib/ant-launcher.jar org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

It is need to have `ANT_HOME` as a system variable or specify the full path to the ant library (`c:/ant/` — is a path to the `ant` installation).

```
java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -cp c:/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

**Update Java 7 version**

Also problem can be solved by updating the Java 7 version. But the last available version (`7u80`) doesn't fix the problem. It is need to use update provided with Oracle Advanced Support (formerly known as Java for Business).

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven project try to add this in your pom.xml. The reason is maybe that you use an older version of javax.mail. That's working for me.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Found this information in official documentation : https://javaee.github.io/javamail/