# Maven: No plugin found for prefix 'install'

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Last week my hard drive broke. Therfore I had to setup my system from scratch.

After donwloading some git projects and installing Java and Maven manually I tried to build my project again. But Maven says "no".

In my project I have some third party dependencies (2 JARs in the same project folder). My first step is to "install" those manually to the local maven repo.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/myjar.jar -DgroupId=com.my.group.id -DartifactId=MyArtifactId -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

But Maven says "no".

```
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:
```

...

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project and in the plugin groups
```

I searched for a couple of days but I found no solution. In my POV it can not be ralated to network issues like proxy settings. I have full internet access and I checkt with serveral connections. My collegue in the same network has no problems.

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T20:49:05+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Java 7, which deserves extra attention when connection to Maven Central. About a month ago it can only be accessed via TLSv1.2. See [Why am I getting "Received fatal alert: protocol_version" or "peer not authenticated" from Maven Central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic) for all the details.