# Maven Fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, oracle, maven, java-7

I have a problem with Maven. I use as environment

- Windows 10
- Java SE JDK Version 8 update 80
- Eclipse Mars 2 with M2Eclipse
- Maven 3.5.4

I try to use any of the two but the protocol_version error arises.
enable TLS 1.2 in the java application. But it does not work.

I was looking at this solution:

- [Why am I getting "Received fatal alert: protocol_version" or "peer not authenticated" from Maven Central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic)

but I do not understand how to make the addition of -Dhttps.protocols = TLSv1.2. no where is it made.

thank you very much for your time, excuse my english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic) and the issue was solved. You should try to add the parameter "**-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2**" in your command and try.

Answer (score 1):

> but I do not understand how to make the addition of -Dhttps.protocols = TLSv1.2. no where is it made

This depends on how you're building your Application.

**A** : if you're building with Eclipse Run button, you'll have to edit Run Configuration (of maven build) as shown below.
(nb. you will NOT enter `-D` here)

[image]

B :  If you're running build command line on your windows console, you can run argument right after your [maven build goals](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-goals-phases)

`mvn clean install -Dhttps.protocols = TLSv1.2`

See [this link](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) for more details on Command line arguments for maven build