# unable to start grails application

Tags: grails

Hi since 2 days i've got an error i can't understand when i try to run my app asset pipeline have some trouble

> Error |Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:1.9.9 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: protocol_version (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

If any idea for these kind of problems known that i've the same issues with all my grails version

Comment: Please share environment details (like grails version, java version, etc).

Comment: This most likely due to an old java version. Search for the `protocol_version` error.  E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529054/maven-fatal-alert-protocol-version

Comment: Given that you are using asset-pipeline 1.9.9 this looks like it is probably an older version of Grails.  If you are using any version of Grails prior to 2.5 then you will need to use a JDK version less than 8.  Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we support Java 8.  I don't know if that is the issue you are having or not, a little bit of a shot in the dark.

Comment: Solved by changing the version of jdk from 1.7 to 1.8.0_31
thanks to @cfrick

Comment: Why not update to a recent version. I'd bet a recent 1.7 from e.g. azul would be better than this ages old 1.8 you are now using

Comment: "Solved by changing the version of jdk from 1.7 to 1.8.0_31" - What version of Grails are you using that is compatible with both asset-pipeline 1.9.9 and Java 8?