# Failed to resolve dependencies of Vaadin 7.6.2 with Ivy

Tags: java, maven, ssl, vaadin, ivy

I can't resolve the my vaadin 7 project using Apache Ivy. Whenever I tried, it shows an error box which says

> 'IvyDE resolve' has encountered a problem. Some project fails to be
>   resolved.

On clicking Details button on the error box, I got the following additional information

> Some projects fail to be resolved Impossible to resolve dependencies
>   of com.example#v7proj;working@User unresolved dependency:
>   com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiled;7.6.2: not found unresolved
>   dependency: com.vaadin#vaadin-themes;7.6.2: not found unresolved
>   dependency: com.vaadin#vaadin-push;7.6.2: not found unresolved
>   dependency: com.vaadin#vaadin-server;7.6.2: not found unresolved
>   dependency: com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiler;7.6.2: not found
>   unresolved dependency: com.vaadin#vaadin-client;7.6.2: not found
>   unresolved dependency: javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1: not
>   found

**ivy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ivy-module [
    <!ENTITY vaadin.version "7.6.2">
]>
<ivy-module version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="com.example" module="v7proj" />
    <configurations>
        <!-- The default configuration, which should be deployed to the server -->
        <conf name="default" />
        <!-- A configuration only needed when compiling the widget set. Should 
            not be deployed to the server -->
        <conf name="widgetset-compile" />
        <!-- A configuration used in compilation of server side classes only.
            Should be deployed to the server -->
        <conf name="nodeploy" />
    </configurations>
    <dependencies defaultconf="default" defaultconfmapping="default->default">
        <!-- The core server part of Vaadin -->
        <dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-server" rev="&vaadin.version;" />

        <!-- Vaadin themes -->
        <dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-themes" rev="&vaadin.version;" />

        <!-- Push support -->
        <dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-push" rev="&vaadin.version;" />

        <!-- Servlet 3.0 API -->
        <dependency org="javax.servlet" name="javax.servlet-api" rev="3.0.1" conf="nodeploy->default" />

        <!-- Precompiled DefaultWidgetSet -->
        <dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-client-compiled"
            rev="&vaadin.version;" />

        <!-- Vaadin client side, needed for widget set compilation -->
        <dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-client" rev="&vaadin.version;"
             conf="widgetset-compile->default" />

        <!-- Compiler for custom widget sets. Should not be deployed -->
        <dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-client-compiler"
            rev="&vaadin.version;" conf="widgetset-compile->default" />

    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**ivysettings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="default" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="default">
            <!-- Public Maven repository -->
            <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" />

            <!-- Vaadin Add-on repository -->
            <ibiblio name="vaadin-addons" usepoms="true" m2compatible="true"
                root="http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons" />

            <!-- Vaadin snapshots repository -->
            <ibiblio name="vaadin-snapshots" usepoms="true" m2compatible="true"
                root="https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots" />
            <!-- Repository used for Vaadin modified smartsprites library -->
            <dual name="custom-smartsprites">
                <filesystem name="smartsprites-ivy">
                    <ivy pattern="${basedir}/ivymodule/[module]-ivy-[revision].xml" />
                </filesystem>
                <url name="smartsprites-artifact">
                    <artifact
                        pattern="http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/versions/6.8/build/smartsprites/lib/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" />
                </url>
            </dual>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <!-- Vaadin patched SmartSprites -->
        <module organisation="com.carrotsearch" name="smartsprites"
            revision="0.2.3-itmill" resolver="custom-smartsprites" />
    </modules>


</ivysettings>
```

I checked the repository [Central Repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/), it contains all the required jars. Then why it is not resolving ?

**UPDATE :**

I checked the Ivy console and found the following logs

```
[IvyDE] Resolve job starting...
[IvyDE] Processing resolve request ivy.xml[*] in MyProject
[IvyDE] 1 module(s) to resolve outside the workspace
[IvyDE] Resolving ivy.xml[*] in MyProject
:: resolving dependencies :: com.example#v7proj;working@Shakir
    confs: [default, widgetset-compile, nodeploy]
:: resolution report :: resolve 22ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   4   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
    | widgetset-compile|   2   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
    |     nodeploy     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: com.vaadin#vaadin-server;7.6.2

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-server\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-server;7.6.2!vaadin-server.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-server\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-server.jar

    ==== shared: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-server\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-server;7.6.2!vaadin-server.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-server\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-server.jar

    ==== public: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-server/7.6.2/vaadin-server-7.6.2.pom

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-server;7.6.2!vaadin-server.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-server/7.6.2/vaadin-server-7.6.2.jar

        module not found: com.vaadin#vaadin-themes;7.6.2

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-themes\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-themes;7.6.2!vaadin-themes.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-themes\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-themes.jar

    ==== shared: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-themes\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-themes;7.6.2!vaadin-themes.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-themes\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-themes.jar

    ==== public: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-themes/7.6.2/vaadin-themes-7.6.2.pom

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-themes;7.6.2!vaadin-themes.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-themes/7.6.2/vaadin-themes-7.6.2.jar

        module not found: com.vaadin#vaadin-push;7.6.2

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-push\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-push;7.6.2!vaadin-push.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-push\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-push.jar

    ==== shared: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-push\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-push;7.6.2!vaadin-push.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-push\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-push.jar

    ==== public: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-push/7.6.2/vaadin-push-7.6.2.pom

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-push;7.6.2!vaadin-push.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-push/7.6.2/vaadin-push-7.6.2.jar

        module not found: com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiled;7.6.2

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-client-compiled\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiled;7.6.2!vaadin-client-compiled.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-client-compiled\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-client-compiled.jar

    ==== shared: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-client-compiled\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiled;7.6.2!vaadin-client-compiled.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-client-compiled\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-client-compiled.jar

    ==== public: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiled/7.6.2/vaadin-client-compiled-7.6.2.pom

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiled;7.6.2!vaadin-client-compiled.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiled/7.6.2/vaadin-client-compiled-7.6.2.jar

        module not found: com.vaadin#vaadin-client;7.6.2

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-client\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-client;7.6.2!vaadin-client.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-client\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-client.jar

    ==== shared: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-client\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-client;7.6.2!vaadin-client.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-client\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-client.jar

    ==== public: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/7.6.2/vaadin-client-7.6.2.pom

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-client;7.6.2!vaadin-client.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/7.6.2/vaadin-client-7.6.2.jar

        module not found: com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiler;7.6.2

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-client-compiler\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiler;7.6.2!vaadin-client-compiler.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\com.vaadin\vaadin-client-compiler\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-client-compiler.jar

    ==== shared: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-client-compiler\7.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiler;7.6.2!vaadin-client-compiler.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\com.vaadin\vaadin-client-compiler\7.6.2\jars\vaadin-client-compiler.jar

    ==== public: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiler/7.6.2/vaadin-client-compiler-7.6.2.pom

      -- artifact com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiler;7.6.2!vaadin-client-compiler.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiler/7.6.2/vaadin-client-compiler-7.6.2.jar

        module not found: javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\javax.servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1!javax.servlet-api.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\local\javax.servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\jars\javax.servlet-api.jar

    ==== shared: tried

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\javax.servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1!javax.servlet-api.jar:

      C:\Users\Shakir\.ivy2\shared\javax.servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\jars\javax.servlet-api.jar

    ==== public: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.pom

      -- artifact javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1!javax.servlet-api.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: com.vaadin#vaadin-server;7.6.2: not found

        :: com.vaadin#vaadin-themes;7.6.2: not found

        :: com.vaadin#vaadin-push;7.6.2: not found

        :: com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiled;7.6.2: not found

        :: com.vaadin#vaadin-client;7.6.2: not found

        :: com.vaadin#vaadin-client-compiler;7.6.2: not found

        :: javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:::: ERRORS
Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-server/7.6.2/vaadin-server-7.6.2.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-server/7.6.2/vaadin-server-7.6.2.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-themes/7.6.2/vaadin-themes-7.6.2.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-themes/7.6.2/vaadin-themes-7.6.2.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-push/7.6.2/vaadin-push-7.6.2.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-push/7.6.2/vaadin-push-7.6.2.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiled/7.6.2/vaadin-client-compiled-7.6.2.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiled/7.6.2/vaadin-client-compiled-7.6.2.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/7.6.2/vaadin-client-7.6.2.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/7.6.2/vaadin-client-7.6.2.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiler/7.6.2/vaadin-client-compiler-7.6.2.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiler/7.6.2/vaadin-client-compiler-7.6.2.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
[IvyDE] Error on resolve of ivy.xml[*] in MyProject: Impossible to resolve dependencies of com.example#v7proj;working@Shakir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is issue in Ivy, it uses old TLS 1.0 version by default, which is not supported by maven central anymore. You need to reconfigure it. You can find more information from [Vaadin Forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17122531/17583310) and another StackOverflow question [Why am I getting "Received fatal alert: protocol_version" or "peer not authenticated" from Maven Central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic)

Comment: I tried setting system property https.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2. But didn't work for me. Then I noticed http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ is still available. So I changed the root of my public resolver in ivysettings.xml.

Answer (score -1):

Add next code into ivysettings.xml

```
<url name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true">
            <artifact pattern="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </url>
```

Comment: Please add some steps and describe how it worls