# Unable to read repository at http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/juno/content.xml. Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, eclipse

Tried to install glassfish server tools in eclipse juno but i was unable to and got this error message Unable to read repository at http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/juno/content.xml.
Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Help 
i use java 6

Thanks

Comment: Upgrade to Java 8 or higher. The error is probably caused by the server requiring TLSv1.2 or even higher, which is not supported in Java 6 IIRC.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic)