# Maven dependencies could not be downloaded

Tags: java, maven

I use Java 7 and Maven 3.2. When I try to run

> mvn clean install

I got the following error

> [ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
> Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:jar:1.8:
> Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:pom:1.8 from/to
> central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2):
> Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]

However, if I switch to Java 8 I can run

> mvn lean install

with no issues. I have access to  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/1.8/build-helper-maven-plugin-1.8.pom via Google Chrome but maven can't download it. What might be the problem?

Comment: Btw, I don't use any proxies in my network.

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Received fatal alert: protocol\_version" or "peer not authenticated" from Maven Central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic)

Comment: Smells like an SSL/TLS problem, and I expect the duplicate that Himanshu suggested is the culprit.

Comment: If using JDK 7 you have to force Java 7 to use TLSv1.2 (-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 if I correctly remember)...

Comment: Another solution - don't use Java 7.  The last public (free) updates for Java 7 were in 2015.

Comment: Furthermore Upgrade Maven to most recent version.... Maven 3.2 is bit old...