# i got following error while build mvn clean install

Tags: maven

sudo mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.2.RELEASE.pom

[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.careinsurance.crosssell:crosssellservice:1.0 (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cross_sell/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): peer not authenticated and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 6, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
[Pipeline] }

Comment: This: `peer not authenticated a` looks like a proxy problem...

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic